# Yii2 viaTable join condition

Tags: php, mysql, join, activerecord, yii2

Is it possible to set condition in join section in viaTable?
Currently I got this:

```
return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_user'])
                    ->from(User::tableName())
                    ->viaTable(RoomActiveUser::tableName(), ['id_room' => 'id'],
                        function($query) {
                        return $query->andWhere(['id_role' => 
                                 RoleHelper::getConsultantRole()->id]);
                    });
```

But it's not a good solution. Why? 
When you do a left join the `id_role` condition will make it inner join actually. The `id_role` condition should be placed inside `ON` section of the join.

I was searching the web plus inspecting the code but I don't see how it could be solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the answer from Qiang Xue - `$query->onCondition()` should be used for what I need. Result code:

```
return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_user'])
                    ->from(User::tableName())
                    ->viaTable(RoomActiveUser::tableName(), ['id_room' => 'id'], 
                        function($query) {
                          $query->onCondition(['id_role' => 
                             RoleHelper::getConsultantRole()->id]);
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like

```
->viaTable(RoomActiveUser::tableName(), ['id_room' => 'id', 'id_role' => RoleHelper::getConsultantRole()->id])
```

This should create a `JOIN X on 'id_room' = 'id' AND 'id_role' = '$ConsultantRole_id'`

Comment: Nope. It will tell you there is no column id or no column 1 (if id is 1). I got the answer from Qiang Xue, founder of Yii. I'll post the answer.

Comment: yep, that sounds about right. I remember some time ago I had a similar problem. I solved it by creating a parametric relation in the end.

Comment: I think this can be easily solved by splitting conditions and using after viaTable statement 
 ->onCondition(['id_role' => RoleHelper::getConsultantRole()->id])